# Hartley Oscillator Simulation

Tags: oscillator, ltspice

Hello i want to simulate the following Hartley Oscillator that i designed on LTspice
[image]

But when i run it i am not getting the sine output. Where is the issue? How can i get a correct output?

[image]
UPDATE circuit after suggested changes
[image]

Comment: You need to add something to start-up the oscillation. I usually use a **current source** for that which generates a **short current pulse**. Connect that current source in parallel with any of the component that determine the oscillating frequency, so L1 or C1. Also search and browse this site as this question has been asked many times before!

Comment: Thanks i added a 1 A current source in parallel with L1 but there isn't any change.

Comment: *Thanks i added a 1 A current source in parallel with L1* Does that current source deliver a **constant current** or ** a short current pulse**? Also 1 A is **way too much**, use 100 uA instead. Also your circuit is **wrong**, R3 and L2 basically **do nothing**, see Andy's answer. Also I have my doubts if this circuit will **work at all** as the gain of the amplifier (128k/100k) seems a bit low to me. I could be wrong though.

Comment: *Hartley Oscillator that i designed on LTspice* OK, then **show us you proof that it even CAN work**. My claim: this circuit cannot work as the loopgain is too low. Now **prove me wrong** by showing your calculations. You cannot simply "design something" and then complain here that it doesn't work. You appear to be in "tweak until it works" mode and **trust me** that's not going to work. I know, I have been there too and realized 25 years ago that that is not the way to go.

Comment: About the gain, what i know that for the Hartley oscillator gain A=L2/L1

Comment: Your `V2` has a negative value, but it's upside down. If you had drawn the schematic in a human readable way, you'd have spotted the error.

Comment: *the Hartley oscillator gain A=L2/L1* So the values of resistors R1 and R2 do not matter? Hmm, if you think that this is true then you **really** need to study oscillators in more detail before you should even attempt to design one. Also look at what values Andy used in his circuit in his answer for those resistors and note how his circuit does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 384 ohm resistor is in the wrong place: -

[image]

You may also need to lower R1 to allow the circuit to initiate and sustain oscillations.

The OP-07 is going to struggle with the operating frequency - try making C1 ten to one hundred times higher initially.

Don't be too surprised if sine purity isn't outstanding.

Here's a simulation result: -

[image]

Because the OP-07 is a bit crappy on bandwidth, I increased the capacitor from 4.4 pf to 4.4 nF to lower the oscillation frequency 30 odd times, left R1 at 100 kohm (so it didn't load the output too much) and made the feedback resistor 1 Mohm: -

[image]

Sometimes you have to experiment with values. You can get oscillation higher frequencies if you lower the inductance values by 100:1 and the sine-wave purity is much better.

Comment: Thankds i did those changes and and it is still the same

Comment: List the changes you made. Show your modified circuit.

Comment: Thanks i updated my question with the modified circuit

Comment: Why have you changed R2 to 1.28 kohms? Did I tell you to do this? Why haven't you changed the 4.4 pF to something like 440 pF. I told you to do this. Get rid of the current source also.

Comment: Sorry, i just tried with a 440 pF the  result is the same

Comment: Thank you very much with the 4400pF it worked! So there is no way i can still have the 4.4pF and make the circuit work?

Comment: Yes i will accept it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: An op-07 won't hack it with 4.4 pF. Much faster op-amps should.

Comment: @user287001 you don't seem to have brought anything to the party.

Answer (score 0):

The resonant frequency of 10pF and 0.1 henry is

Fres = 1/(2 * PI * sqrt (L * C)) = 0.159/sqrt(0.1 * 10e-12)

Fres = 0.159 / sqrt(1e-12) = 0.159 * 1,000,000 = 159,000 Hertz.

Does the opamp have much usable gain, at 160KHz?